# How to cover a div

Tags: html

Let's say we have a div as follow:

```
<div class="post">Variable text</div>
```

The text can be any longer. So it could be 3 characters, 150 or 300.
The div has a border of `border: 1 px solid black` over a `background: white`. 
Is there any way to create another div (with position `relative` or `absolute` i guess) that completely covers this div so that the text is unreadable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<div class="post" style="position:relative">
     Variable text
     <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:white"></div>
</div>
```

Something like that could work, you may   have to play with the  z-index to make sure your white box is on top.  Basically, that inner   div starts at the top left corner of the outer div and is the   same size as it.

Comment: Love from me too! :) Thanks for saving hours of frustration mate.

Comment: Thanks just second line worked for me just by one search i got this result.

Answer (score 5):

CSS:

```
.outer { 
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}
.inner {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:20;
 }
```

CSS (image replacement):

```
.outer { 
  text-indent:-9999em;
  height:0;
  padding:100px 0 0 0;
  width:100px;
  background-image:url(100x100.jpg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  Text to Replace
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?  Any reasons you need another div?

If you're just trying to hide the data why don't you just:

```
<div class="post" style="background-color:black;">Variable text</div>
```

And ensure your text is also 'black'

Comment: Because my text could have different color and images and other colored `span` inside.

Comment: Okay - but why are you trying to hide? You realise the user could just view the source?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on why you are trying to do this, but I wondered if you have considered hiding your div completely using the visibility:hidden; css style.